# What is "relaxed coating of dust" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I read a paragraph on the [BBC Webpage](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-india-30205289)

> In his interview to the BBC in February, Mr Kejriwal wore a rumpled sweater and his "bare feet were clad in well-worn sandals with **a relaxed coating of dust**".*

What do they mean by "relaxed coating of dust"?

I searched for this phrase, but I cannot find the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it's poetic license.

It adds to the overall image of someone in extremely casual, if not actually scruffy clothes - & who doesn't care about it.

The headline of the article you linked gives that away right at the start…

> The leader of India's newest party, Arvind Kejriwal, is known for his austere lifestyle and simple clothes.

… and goes on entirely about his sense of 'style' or lack thereof. It barely mentions politics at all.

His shoes are dusty. He is relaxed. The addition of 'relaxed' to the description of dusty shoes gives the feeling that this is not a new or temporary condition for his shoes; it is how they always are.
The combination of the two ideas is imaginary, yet conveys the imagery of his lack of concern with his visual appearance.

An aside - dust could also be described as agitated, disturbed, angry, insidious - all of which are anthropomorphic terms to give the idea of some kind of emotional state to an inanimate substance.

Comment: well explained! +1

Answer (score 4):

A *comfortable chair* is not, itself, comfortable, but the person sitting in it is supposed to be.

*A relaxed coating of dust* works in a similar way. The coating of dust on the sandals shows that the person wearing the sandals did not bother about cleaning them before coming to the interview. That is seen as a sign that that person is relaxed.

Searching on the phrase is probably not very helpful, since it is not a standard phrase. It *is* a common way of applying adjectives, though. For example, a *demure skirt* does not actually mean the skirt is shy or modest, but rather, the woman *wearing* it.

Comment: +1 too good! :) however, a little query. The structure of *a comfortable chair* and *a relaxed coating **of** dust* is different. The word that has confused the OP is probably *relaxed* with *dust* and not anything that we generally find relaxing i.e. chair, bed, movie!

Comment: The (presence of the) dust indicates the relaxed state of mind. It simply is _not_ a common association, so I cannot make it common :)

Comment: err...no. I wouldn't say _comfortable chair_ and _a demure skirt_ are similar to _a relaxed coating of dust_ in terms of usage. At least the supposed similarity you propose isn't what the op seems to be asking about.

Comment: @Sam: could you elaborate on why the usage is so different in your eyes? I agree that the layer of dust is not strictly _worn_ by the person that the adjective _relaxed_ applies to, but it is directly related to that person, in the same way the chair is related to the sitter and the skirt is related to the wearer.

Answer (score -1):

I think they are just talking about a very thin layer of dust that had settled on his sandals. "so it is not copious amounts of dust but a very relaxed layer.

Answer (score -1):

It means he was a chill dude and therefore he hadn't washed his feet as an up-tight, foot-washing sort might do. Perhaps not lazy, quite... but just relaxed, man.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but I'm a native English speaker. I'm not sure this is is helpful to someone who is learning English.

Comment: You're right. I've removed the word "like" so that it's grammatically correct now.